# Windows Azure openSUSE: rcnetwork not starting

Tags: opensuse, daemon, azure

I have a Linux VM in Azure, created from their default image.

My problem is simply that the init script `network` doesn't look like to start, so dependent services (apache, postfix...) won't start.

If I run `yast runlevel` and try to start `postfix` it asks me to start `network` first: if I accept, network is started without errors and then postfix is started.

While `network` is configured to start on boot, it just doesn't **appear** to have started. Anyway, SSH connections work fine.

Currently, I had to edit my init scripts and remove `network` from the `Required-Start` list, but that didn't work for posftix (even after running `systemctl --system daemon-reload`).

How can I fix all this?

Answer (score 0):

You say that SSH is working, if this is true then your network is starting.

I bet the real problem is that you have not configured any endpoints in the Azure control panel. By default, Azure VPS dont have any endpoints apart from 22 for SSH on linux and the default RDP port on windows.

Log into your azure control panel, open the VPS dashboard, and create new endpoints for the services you want to access from the Internet.

This link has information on how to create endpoints
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/how-to-guides/setup-endpoints/

Comment: I already have a few endpoints setup, including HTTP/HTTPS, SMTP, FTP. Endpoint configuration affects load-balancer configuration (route traffic from VIP to IIP + loadbalance between multiple endpoints if required). Network script runs at VPS's local level